# Geolocation API not working in Firefox Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mobile, geolocation

I'm using the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) for some experiments in a web app, however I have problems making it work in Firefox Mobile.

I'm just using the basic `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition` methods.
Everything works fine on desktop, in Chrome for Android and even in Safari iOS, but when it comes to Firefox the position is never retreived.

The strange thing is that I have the same bugged behavior using the smarthone simultaion from the delevoper tools in Firefox Desktop (`ctrl+shift+M` on Ubuntu, and then choose any smartphone as device).

You can use this demo as test - https://www.audero.it/demo/geolocation-api-demo.html. The behavior is the same in my application:

- I'm asked for the permission to share the location correctly
- no console errors
- position is never retrieved
- on the real smartphone i get an `position acquisition timed out` as result of the error callback in the `watchPosition` method, on the simultated smartphone I got nothing

I can't figure what the problem could be.
Any of you ever faced something similar?

Thanks a lot,
Francesco

Comment: if you set enableHighAccuracy=false it works on Firefox Mobile (but not on smartphone simulation on Firefox Desktop). Maybe you need to increase timeout and ensure that GPS is turned on if you need high accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @Pascal I confirm that with `enableHighAccuracy=false` it works on Firfox Mobile.
In an outdoor scenario the precision is around 20m nerverthless, so it's an acceptable workaround.